# Why is nginx using different error log file?

Tags: nginx, logging, root, nginx-config, privileges

I have defined following global settings in `nginx.conf`:

```
access_log            /tmp/nginx/access.log;
error_log             /tmp/nginx/error.log info;
client_body_temp_path /tmp/nginx/client-body;
```

But `nginx -c nginx.conf` still gives following errors:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied) 2021/08/26

14:11:05 [emerg] 15099#0: mkdir() "/var/tmp/nginx/client-body" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

What gives?

Comment: Run `nginx -T |grep error_log` and check if you have any other `error_log` directive somewhere.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I'm running nginx as user without sudo, `nginx -T` gives same errors. It also mentions `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: What do you mean by _global settings_? Are they located at the **main** context or **http** or **server** one? You can also check `nginx -V` to see build parameters, check `--error-log-path=...` and `--http-client-body-temp-path=..` ones.